# estimating effect with marginaleffect package

Tags: propensity-scores, matching, treatment-effect, marginal-effect, separation

I want to estimate ATE. first of all I used MatchIt package for full matching  for propensity score and then I used logistic regression with all of variable in propensity score model after that I used marginal effect package for estimating causal effect with G-computation.

I noticed one of variable in outcome model have big standard deviation. my question is: I have to remove this variable and after that use marginal effect package or with out removing this variable the effect is true?

Comment: Why do you think you have to remove the variable?  What does the standard deviation (or perhaps the standard error) tell you about this variable?

Comment: I think it's because of seperation